# Common info window

Tags: html, maps, markers

I am creating a map with markers and I would like to have a common window placed in the top right hand corner of the map so that whenever a user clicks on a marker, the marker info is displayed in that info window. This doesn't to be an info window, it could be a div and is there a way, I can have more than one marker's info at the same time (i.e. have two div that display previous clicked markers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapbox API solved my issues.